# Customized post loops

Tags: php, wordpress

Let say I have one default post category and one custom category called “my_name”.

EDIT

Comment: It qould be a-single-loop-with-an-if-statement-and-two-iterators difficult

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: I only have the basic post loop :P

Comment: Does that query pull posts from both categories?

Comment: no. This only pulls posts from the default categories. I can include `'cat=3'` as the post cat, but I thought I would leave it empty for clarity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code.

I don't have the exact code right now but it helps a lot to you.

```
    $args = array( 
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'posts_per_page' => 20,         
        'orderby' => 'date',            
        'order' => 'DESC'
        );
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
$catDefaultArray = array();
$catBArray = array();
foreach ($loop as $post) {
    if($post->post_category == "default"){
        $catDefaultArray[] =$post; 
    } else if($post->post_category == "B"){
        $catBArray[] = $post;
    }
}

$finalArray = array();
$j = 0;
for($i = 0 ; $i < count($catDefaultArray) ; $i++){
    if($i % 3 == 0){
        $finalArray[] = $catDefaultArray[$i];
    } else {
        $finalArray[] = $catBArray[$j];
        $j++;
    }
}
```

Comment: I included my post loop that I have. How would you implement what you have into the post loop? thanks!

Comment: can u please explained? Or plz upload your code snippet @steveKim